# Exponential of Frobeniushomomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Let $\phi_p: R \to R,\ \ x \mapsto x^p$ with $R$ a field and $char R=p$ with $p$ prime, be the Frobenius-Homormophism.

Furthermore, let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a field with $q=p^n,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ elements. Then the exponentiated Frobenius-Homomorphism $\phi_p^n\colon x\mapsto x^{p^{n}}$ is the identity on $\mathbb{F}_q$.

I am not able to proof this, somehow. I know that for the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$ (p still prime) we have $a^p=a,a\in \mathbb{F}_p$ but I can not extend this to $\mathbb{F}_q$, since $\mathbb{F}_q$ is different from $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

The only thing i can say that for every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ we have that $\phi_p^n(x^{p^n})=x$. But there are elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ which are not in $\mathbb{F_p}$.

Comment: Also if $a \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ then $a^q = a$ iff $a \in \mathbb{F}_q$ because the polynomial $x^q-x$ of degree $q$ already has $q$ roots in the subfield $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\Bbb F_q$ the multiplicative group has order $q-1$. So each nonzero
element satisfies $x^{q-1}=1$, so that $x^q=x$ etc.